# Which are the available domain operators in Openerp / Odoo?

Tags: odoo, operators, odoo-8

I know few operator in openerp domain. I dont get the details of available domains and their explanation. Particularly for these negation domains. Can anyone tell me the detail list?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This gives a overview:

List of **Domain** operators: `!` (Not), `|` (Or), `&` (And)

List of **Term** operators: `'=', '!=', '<=', '<', '>', '>=', '=?', '=like', '=ilike', 'like', 'not like', 'ilike', 'not ilike', 'in', 'not in', 'child_of'`

**Usage**:

Input records:

Record 1: `Openerp`

Record 2: `openerp`

Record 3: `Opensource`

Record 4: `opensource`

Record 5: `Open`

Record 6: `open`

Record 7: `Odoo`

Record 8: `odoo`

Record 9: `Odooopenerp`

Record 10: `OdooOpenerp`

**'like':** `[('input', 'like', 'open')]` -  Returns case sensitive (wildcards - '%open%') search.

O/p: open, opensource, openerp, Odooopenerp

**'not like':** `[('input', 'not like', 'open')]` -  Returns results not matched with case sensitive (wildcards - '%open%') search.

O/p: Openerp, Opensource, Open, Odoo, odoo, OdooOpenerp

**'=like':** `[('name', '=like', 'open')]` - Returns exact (=  'open') case sensitive search.

O/p: open

**'ilike':** `[('name', 'ilike', 'open')]` - Returns exact case insensitive (wildcards - '%open%') search.

O/p: Openerp, openerp, Opensource, opensource, Open, open, Odooopenerp, OdooOpenerp

**'not ilike':** `[('name', 'not ilike', 'open')]` - Returns results not matched with exact case insensitive (wildcards - '%open%') search.

O/p: Odoo, odoo

**'=ilike':** `[('name', '=ilike', 'open')]` - Returns exact (=  'open' or 'Open') case insensitive search.

O/p: Open, open

**'=?':**

name = 'odoo'
parent_id = False
`[('name', 'like', name), ('parent_id', '=?', parent_id)]` - Returns name domain result & True

name = 'odoo'
parent_id = 'openerp'
`[('name', 'like', name), ('parent_id', '=?', parent_id)]` - Returns name domain result & parent_id domain result

**'=?'** is a short-circuit that makes the term TRUE if right is None or False, `'=?'` behaves like `'='` in other cases

**'in':**
`[('value1', 'in', ['value1', 'value2'])]` - in operator will check the value1 is present or not in list of right term

**'not in':**
`[('value1', 'not in', ['value2'])]` - not in operator will check the value1 is not present in list of right term
While these 'in' and 'not in' works with list/tuple of values, the latter 
`'='` and `'!='` works with string

**'=':**
value = 10
`[('value','=',value)]` - term left side has 10 in db and term right our value 10 will match

**'!=':**
value = 15
`[('value','!=',value)]` - term left side has 10 in db and term right our value 10 will not match

**'child_of':**
parent_id = '1' #Agrolait
'child_of':
`[('partner_id', 'child_of', parent_id)]` - return left and right list of partner_id for given parent_id

**'<=', '<', '>', '>=':**
These operators are largely used in openerp for comparing dates - `[('date', '>=', date_begin), ('date', '<=', date_end)]`. You can use these operators to compare int or float also.

Comment: The arity for the **not** operator is one, for the **or** operator is two, and for the **and** operator is two. So if you need to **or** three terms use two **or** operators, if you need to **or** four terms use three **or** operators, et cetera.

Comment: helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score -9):

condition A and condition B for in domain in filter syntax is like

```
<filter name="filtering" string="Filtering" domain="[(A),(B)]" />
```