# Odoo Uncaught Error: NameError: name '' is not defined error

Tags: python, odoo, nameerror

I tried to pass a list to check in domain field in view side. But when I execute it displayed  a error that telling the passing variable was defined

In python file

```
class generate_time_table_line(osv.osv_memory):
@api.onchange('lecturer_id')
def onchange_lecturer(self):
    if self.lecturer_id:
        global list_new
        list_new =[1]
        return list_new
```

in view file

```
<record id="view_gen_time_table_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">gen.time.table.line.tree</field>
        <field name="model">gen.time.table.line</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="8" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="TimeTable Line" editable="top">
                <field name="day" />
                <field name="period_id" />
                <field name="lecturer_id"  />
                <field name="subject_id" domain="[('id','=',list_new)]"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

error

```
Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'list_new' is not defined
```

Comment: Why have you got that `global` statement there? Especially since you're returning the value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, to avoid the error, `list_new` should be a field name.

Second, in the domain you are comparing an id (integer?) with a list. Maybe you meant 'in' instead of '='

Comment: because of this error i created a list called list_new , out side of the function with few ids and check the domain.. its working perfectly.. But its displaying the error when i try to pass the list through the function.

Answer (score 0):

A domain is a list of criteria, each criterion being a triple (either a list or a tuple) of `(field_name, operator, value)` where:

`field_name` (str) is a field name of the current model, or a relationship traversal through a `Many2one` using dot-notation e.g. `'street'` or `'partner_id.country'`

`operator (str)` is an operator used to compare the field_name with the value. Some valid operators are: `=`, `!=`. You can find all the available domain operators and their use cases here [Available domain operator in openerp/odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29443027/3374651)

`value` is a variable type, must be comparable (through operator) to the named field.

So in your code,

If you put `list_new` on a domain in `python` file means, `list_new` should be a valid variable which produces a value or a valid field name. In the later, ORM will compute the value for you.

If you put `list_new` on a domain in `xml` file means, `list_new` should be a valid `field_name`.

I think the following may fit your need to generate dynamic domains:

Use a functional field to save the domain and use that field in view like

```
def _get_domain(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    record_id = ids[0] 
    # do some computations....
    return {record_id: YOUR DOMAIN} 

'list_new': fields.function(_get_domain, type='char', size=255, method=True, string="Domain"),
```

and in xml:

```
<field name="subject_id" domain="list_new" />
```

Another way is `fields_view_get()` function. But i would not recommend this.

Comment: I get an error that says the field data is not JSON serializable.  I doubt you are meant to pass a dictionary as char.