# Both sql and python constraints are not working in odoo 9

Tags: methods, odoo, odoo-9

I have been battling with this for a while. none of the two options are working neither were they giving errors. i commented the pythonic constrain method for you to see.

code snippet:

```
class house_development(models.Model):
    _name = 'house.development'
    _description = 'Development'
    _inherit = ["mail.thread"]

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True, track_visibility='onchange')
    description = fields.Text(string="Description", track_visibility='onchange')

    # @api.one
    # @api.constrains('name')
    # def _identify_same_name(self):
    #     for record in self:
    #         if record.name in self:
    #             raise exceptions.ValidationError("There is another development/project with the same name: %s" % record.name)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('name_unique',
         'UNIQUE(name)',
         "There is another development/project with the same name"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like that,

```
@api.multi
@api.constrains('name')
def _identify_same_name(self):
    for record in self:
        obj = self.search([('name','=ilike',record.name),('id','!=',record.id)])
        if obj:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError("There is another development/project with the same name: %s" % record.name)
```

You need to search for the same name but not with the same id.

And for database unique constrains you may add like that.

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('name_unique', 'unique(name)', 'There is another development/project with the same name!!!'),
]
```

> Database constrains will not be added if there are duplicate name in
>   table. Sql constrains will apply only if the rule is not violated by
>   the existing data. I think in your case that's the point with Sql
>   constrains. And make sure for that you need to upgrade module. first
>   check duplicate records in database by firing that query.

```
Select name, count(*) from table_name 
group by name
having count(*) > 1;
```

Available operators in domain in odoo [Click to see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442993/available-domain-operator-in-openerp-odoo).

Comment: Thanks so much Emipro Tech, it works but i realised that if i input 'house' and 'House', it bypass the constrains and get saved. How can i include this case sensitivity in the code? Secondly, why did you use @api.multi instead of @api.one?

Comment: Thanks real good man.....why did you use @api.multi instead of @api.one?

Comment: If you use @api.one then in self only one record will be available while you bulk update then multiple records will be there in self.